# lambdas work alone but not when invoked by another lambda despite VPN, kms-key and policy all being correct

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sam-cli

I have 2 lambdas and 3 sub-directories in an s3 bucket. The first lambda is triggered when a file is uploaded to sub1. It generates an output which is written to sub2. This then triggers lambda 2 which writes an output to sub3. Standard use of lambdas.

The S3 bucket uploads are encrypted with a kms-key, each lambda has this key configured into its environment variables so that it can read/write to the s3.

Each lambda has several policies attached so that it can work: s3crud, VPCAccessPolicy (as they sit within a vpc and 2 subnets) and LambdaInvokePolicy

The are 20k items in sub1 so rather than download all the items and re-upload, I built another lambda which reads all items from the s3 sub-dir, creates an event containing the bucket and key and passes this into lambda 1 to trigger the event. This lambda has the same VPC, policy and kms-key.

Step/lambda 1 works fine and writes the expected output to sub2, but for each step 2 file I get:

```
"An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetObject operation: Access Denied", "errorType": "ClientError"
```

The really weird thing is that if I do a local invoke from sam cli, passing in file names to lambda2 through an event.json, it works fine and writes the expected file to sub3 - suggesting there is nothing wrong with this lambda. But I can't use lambda 3 to invoke lambda 2 en mass, despite it having the relevant kms-key, VPN access and policies. WHy would it work to invoke lambda 1 en-mass but not lambda-2? All of these files are in the same bucket, encrypted with the same kms-key and each lambda has the same key access and sits in the same VPN!

Can anyone think why this would be?

Here is lambda 3:

```
import boto3
import json
import os
import time
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')    

def lambda_handler(event, context):    

    # get list of files in sub dir
    obj_list = []
    bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(event['bucket'])
    for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=event['prefix'],Delimiter='/'):
        obj_list.append(str(obj.key))

     # COUNT: 20440    

    # generate list of event.json to pass into lambdas
    event_list = []
    for key in obj_list[:5]:
        x = make_template()
        x['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'] = key
        x['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name'] = event['bucket']
        event_list.append(x)

    # invoke lambdas
    # setup boto3 and inputs 
    involeLam = boto3.client("lambda", region_name="eu-west-1")
    lambda_to_invoke = event['lambda_to_trigger']

    # invoke the lambda
    invocations = []
    for payload in event_list:
        response = involeLam.invoke(FunctionName = lambda_to_invoke, InvocationType = "RequestResponse", Payload = json.dumps(payload))    # initiate and await response
        invocations.append(response)

    time.sleep(60)

    # parse the contents of the file from the lambda return
    for i in invocations:
        print(i["Payload"].read())



    return {
            "success": True
            }


def make_template():
    template = {  
        "Records":[  
            {  
                "s3":{  
                "bucket":{  
                    "name":"mybucket"
                },
                "object":{  
                    "key":"path/to/file.csv"
                }
                }
            }
        ]
        }
    return template
```

Here is the event.json passed into this lambda:

```
{
  "bucket": "mybucket",
  "prefix": "path/to/my/",
  "lambda_to_trigger":"arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:number:function:MyFunction"

}
```

And here is the template.yaml used to build this lambda:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  triggermultiplelambda

  Sample SAM Template for triggermultiplelambda

Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 120

Resources:
  TriggerMultipleLambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function 
    Properties:
      CodeUri: triggermultiplelambda/
      Handler: triggerMultipleLambda.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.6
      KmsKeyArn: !Sub arn:aws:kms:eu-west-1:number:key/code-for-key
      Policies: 
        - S3CrudPolicy:
            BucketName: "*"
        - VPCAccessPolicy: {}
        - LambdaInvokePolicy:
            FunctionName: "*"

Outputs:
  TriggerMultipleLambdaFunction:
    Description: "TriggerMultipleLambda Lambda Function ARN"
    Value: !GetAtt TriggerMultipleLambdaFunction.Arn
  TriggerMultipleLambdaFunctionIamRole:
    Description: "Implicit IAM Role created for TriggerMultipleLambda function"
    Value: !GetAtt TriggerMultipleLambdaFunctionRole.Arn
```

Let me know if I should post anything else. Many thanks

Comment: Two parts to this. Does the KMS key's own policy allow the Lambda's IAM role to decrypt it? And does the Lambda's IAM role allow it to decrypt the KMS key.

Comment: Also see https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/decrypt-kms-encrypted-objects-s3/

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm not sure: I thought that 'KmsKeyArn: !Sub arn:aws:kms:eu-west-1:number:key/code-for-key' in the template.yaml would allow the lambda to decrypt. I didn't set up the key though so am not sure how to check the KMS key's policy?

Comment: Well, if you don’t have permission to read the key policy to check it then I would go talk to whoever set up the key policy.

Comment: It turns out I do have permission so it wasn't that. I've figured it out, will post below.

Answer (score 0):

At long last I've figured it out. So the template.yaml needs to be modified as follows:

This line (which I had already figured out) needs to be added to Resources: Function: Properties:

```
KmsKeyArn: !Sub arn:aws:kms:eu-west-1:number:key/code-for-key
```

A policy needs to be added to the policies section:

```
- KMSDecryptPolicy:
            KeyId: code-for-key
```

Depending on which boto3 api is used to access the S3 the following lines need to be added to the import statements in the lambda:

```
from botocore.client import Config

# EITHER
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3', config=Config(signature_version='s3v4'))
# OR
s3_client = boto3.client('s3', config=Config(signature_version='s3v4'))
```

With these statements I can now read/download/decrypt files encrypted with a kms key from S3.

To upload files I am using the following line:

```
s3_client.upload_file('/tmp/' + outputfilename, OUTPUTBUCKET, OUTPUTFOLDER+'/'+outputfilename,  
                        ExtraArgs={"ServerSideEncryption": "aws:kms", "SSEKMSKeyId":"code-for-key"})
```

I got this solution from the following urls:

[justdocloud](https://www.justdocloud.com/2018/09/21/upload-download-s3-using-aws-kms-python/)
[reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/9hpken/how_to_use_boto3_download_upload_with_aws_kms/)

Many thanks for your help jarmod, I hope this helps someone!

Comment: OK so it sounds like the specific issue in your case was boto3 defaulting to sigv2.